# How to extend a widget to include new functionality?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Let's imagine ourselves creating a jQuery widget. We're using jquery.ui.widget for the task. We want to create a simple squared div with red borders. Well, let it be our framework for any future extended widgets.

```
(function ($) {
    $.widget('ns.redsquare', {
        _create: function () {
            var elem = this.element;

            elem.css({
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                border: 'solid 1px red'
            });

            $(this.element).appendTo('body');
        }

        // probably a lot of other functionality follows
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('<div/>').redsquare();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

So, the future came. We want to extend our red square so that it contains a squared div with green borders. Certainly, the child should be a bit smaller than the parent. The question is "**How to extend the widget to include new functionality?**". That is, how do we extend (*not change the source code of*) our red square to help our green square have *the parent*? The code of the red square should stay intact; the green square should have its own code but *include all the functionality the red square can probably offer*.

NOTE: The widget example provided hereby is not a real one; it is just another unfortunately example of mine.

Answer (score 1):

Use the process of subclassing explained [here](http://bililite.com/blog/extending-jquery-ui-widgets/).